# What are $\int\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\,\textrm{d}x, \int\sqrt{x^2+a^2}\,\textrm{d}x,\int\sqrt{x^2-a^2}\,\textrm{d}x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Can someone confirm these equations below? I got it from my college textbook, unfortunately there are no proofs and more importantly I cannot seem to find any other sources that say have these equations.

$\displaystyle\int\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\,\textrm{dx}=\frac{x\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{2}+\frac{a^2}{2}\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right) + C$

$\displaystyle\int\sqrt{x^2+a^2}\,\text{dx}=\frac{x\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}{2}+\frac{a^2}{2}\ln\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+a^2}\right)+C$

$\displaystyle\int\sqrt{x^2-a^2}\,\textrm{dx}=\frac{x\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}{2}-\frac{a^2}{2}\ln\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2}\right)+C$

Comment: Try differentiating the right hand sides.

Comment: For verification that the formulas are correct, try what `PM 2Ring` suggested, i.e., differentiate the right side. You can also just use integration by parts to get the closed forms of those integrals. Take the integrand as the first function and $x\mapsto 1$ as the second function during performing IBP.

Answer (score 2):

It's OK to me.

If you just want to confirm it, you may just differentiate each function on the right side to see if you get the integrand on the left hand side.

One may obtain these results by performing respectively the change of variable
$x:=a\sin t$, $x:=a\sinh t$ and $x:=a\cosh t$.